# How can i check if a vector2 (touch input) is inside every rectTransform of a rectTransform[] array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use the function

```
RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint()
```

toghether with a foreach loop, but i'm not getting results..

Here is my code:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (RectTransform rectt in content.GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>())
        {

            if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(rectt, Input.GetTouch(0).position, cam))
            {
                switch (Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
                {
                    case TouchPhase.Began:
                        Debug.Log("BEGAN");
                        scroll.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect>().enabled = false;

                        break;
                    case TouchPhase.Ended:
                        Debug.Log("ENDED");
                        scroll.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect>().enabled = true;

                        break;


                }
            }


        }

    }
```

actually the scroll thing is there because i'm disabling the scrolling of a scrollRect when the touch is inside a rectTransform of the array, or at least that's what i would like to do.

The script is attached to the content of the scrollview.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the RectTransform you are using are of screen space UI elements? In this case, the problem is that UI elements are not associated with a camera, so camera argument passed to the function should be null:

```
if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(rectt, Input.GetTouch(0).position, null))
```

The problem is that is really not clear from the documentation. See here:
http://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?660005_vnn982nkbubqr4qp

Also, keep in mind that in order for `Input.GetTouch` to work, you must have some sort of touch input device, i.e. it will work only on real mobile phone or in editor with Unity Remote.

Comment: i have not a lot of free time to work on this, but i think this could be part of the problem, thank you!